# Detect Hand Orientation (Rotation) in a video

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, mediapipe

I want to detect the rotation of my hand in a video, but I still don't know how to correctly do it.

I tried to use PCA method but it only works for images only not videos.
I can detect the hand and its landmarks correctly

Comment: Can you provide more details? An image which shows what you were able to accomplish? What are the landmarks? Why did you use PCA?

Answer (score 0):

first you can use cv2 for process image use while loop and get frame step by step then use person detection pose detection may enought then find the cordinate of sholder and elbow then change it numpy array then find direction vector by subtracting sholder from elbow then you get direction vector compare you can use it by negetive postive value to find specfic rotation like hands up and hands down if you want more then we could discuss more

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).